# Can't route https request through post method in node.js

Tags: node.js, https, routes

I'm trying to get a Post request to go through HTTPS.  The post request works from the http request, but gets hung up when coming from HTTPS.  The HTTPS part works to load something to the page, but will not answer a post request.  http handles the post no problem, but I need it to go through HTTPS because I think that's how it's supposed to be anyhow, and that's what Android's HttpURLConnection requires.

```
router.post('/users', function(req, res){
    var user = req.body;
    Users.addUsers(user, function(err, user){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }else{
    res.json(user);
}
    });
});

         var pkey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/ssl/37718250_localhost.key'));
         var pcert = fs.readFileSync(path.join    (__dirname, '/ssl/37718250_localhost.cert'));

       var options = {
   key: pkey,
   cert: pcert
    };


     var server = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    }).listen(443);
```

Comment: Do you have an Express app anywhere or just a router? EDIT: Just saw that you have HTTP working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`app.listen`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen), you'll see it's literally this:

```
app.listen = function() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

The `https` module has a similar syntax, so you can do this:

```
var pkey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/ssl/37718250_localhost.key'));
var pcert = fs.readFileSync(path.join    (__dirname, '/ssl/37718250_localhost.cert'));

var options = {
  key: pkey,
  cert: pcert
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(443);
```

The Express `app` is actually just a Function in the form `function(request, response)`, so it can be passed to `http.createServer` and `https.createServer`.

Comment: Wonderfully explained and fixed the problem completely.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a no-op request handler function. Pass your express app instance instead:

`var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);`